# Obtain Values from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please help me to query values from six(6) tables in SQL.

These are the tables:

```
select Pid from BillOrderTbl
select Pid from CustomerCreditItm
select Pid from SalesBillOrderTbl
select Pid from SalesOrderItm
select Pid from VendorCreditItm
select Pid from OrderItm
```

I am trying to do like this.

```
select OrderItm.Pid, BillOrderTbl.Pid, CustomerCreditItm.Pid, SalesBillOrderTbl.Pid, SalesOrderItm.Pid, VendorCreditItm.Pid
from OrderItm
inner join BillOrderTbl on BillOrderTbl.Pid = OrderItm.Pid
inner join CustomerCreditItm on BillOrderTbl.Pid = CustomerCreditItm.Pid
inner join SalesBillOrderTbl on CustomerCreditItm.Pid = SalesBillOrderTbl.Pid
inner join SalesOrderItm on SalesBillOrderTbl.Pid = SalesOrderItm.Pid
inner join VendorCreditItm on SalesOrderItm.Pid = VendorCreditItm.Pid
```

I am getting this output.

[image: Screenshot]

but in actual there is data in `OrderItm.Pid` column.

Comment: There must be a record missing from one of the tables, `inner join` requires there to be a match, maybe you want `left join`?

Comment: Are you trying to find the specific value from the tables.

Comment: For any additional assistance we need to see sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Pid FROM BillOrderTbl
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Pid FROM CustomerCreditItm
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Pid FROM SalesBillOrderTbl
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Pid FROM SalesOrderItm
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Pid FROM VendorCreditItm
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Pid FROM OrderItm
) MyTables
```